# How to load fonts into the dom in Vue3?

Tags: css, fonts, vuejs3, prefetch

I'm having trouble loading fonts into the dom using Vue3.

I'm building an Image Editor using [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)

I tried using a library called [fontfaceobserver](https://fontfaceobserver.com/), but the result is not at all consistent.

Most of the time I keep getting font not loaded error.

Here is my code:

`index.html`

```
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver/master/fontfaceobserver.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat&family=Cormorant+Garamond&family=Dancing+Script&family=Gloria+Hallelujah&family=Hubballi&family=Inter&family=League+Spartan&family=Merriweather&family=Nanum+Brush+Script&family=Niconne&family=Nunito+Sans&family=Permanent+Marker&family=Prompt&family=Reenie+Beanie&family=Roboto&family=Roboto+Condensed&family=Roboto+Mono&family=Roboto+Serif&family=Roboto+Slab&family=Satisfy&family=Shadows+Into+Light&family=Space+Grotesk&family=Ubuntu&family=Yellowtail&display=swap" crossorigin>
```

`Editor.vue`

```
 function changeFontFamily() {
      let activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();

      if (activeObject) {
        loadAndUse(selectedFont.value.name, activeObject.text);
      }
    }

    function loadAndUse(font, text) {
      let activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
      var myfont = new FontFaceObserver(font);
      myfont
        .load()
        .then(function () {
          activeObject.set("fontFamily", font);
          activeObject.set("text", text);
          canvas.renderAll();
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
          console.log(e);
          alert("font loading failed " + font);
        });
    }


<style>
 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat&family=Cormorant+Garamond&family=Dancing+Script&family=Gloria+Hallelujah&family=Hubballi&family=Inter&family=League+Spartan&family=Merriweather&family=Nanum+Brush+Script&family=Niconne&family=Nunito+Sans&family=Permanent+Marker&family=Prompt&family=Reenie+Beanie&family=Roboto&family=Roboto+Condensed&family=Roboto+Mono&family=Roboto+Serif&family=Roboto+Slab&family=Satisfy&family=Shadows+Into+Light&family=Space+Grotesk&family=Ubuntu&family=Yellowtail&display=swap"); 
</style>
```

Comment: Usually, you only need to reach upon the CDN + write them in your CSS. Then, using a `class` on your HTML elements is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Make sure you pass the right font to the `FontFaceObserver`. And try to verify that the font is loaded or not by CSS

Comment: @Anirudh have you got the solution ?